# Download a file from dropbox JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dropbox, dropbox-api

I want to download file from my drop-box using Dropbox API, the API documentation is quite complicated and messy can any one suggest me a simpler approach to download file as my path is:

```
/uploads/2017 0730 Invoice Explanation (1).doc
```

i have find a way but for this approach I have to create a shareable link for the file,  I want to download here is the approach:

```
 function downloadFile() {
        var dbx = new Dropbox({accessToken: 'XXXXXXXXXAAAXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'});
        dbx.sharingGetSharedLinkFile({url: 'https://www.dropbox.com/s/9f4grw8cvqlxwqg/067360_POWERDALE-DEE%20%281%29.KMZ?dl=0'})// here i mentioned the shareable link rather then I want to specify path
            .then(function (data) {
                var downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(data.fileBlob);
                var downloadButton = document.createElement('a');
                downloadButton.setAttribute('href', downloadUrl);
                downloadButton.setAttribute('download', data.name);
                downloadButton.setAttribute('class', 'button');
                downloadButton.innerText = 'Download: ' + data.name;
                document.getElementById('results').appendChild(downloadButton);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.error(error);
            });
        return

    }
```

Using above path can I  download a file any help will be appreciated.

Comment: refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39959444/issues-downloading-files-using-dropbox-javascript-sdk

Comment: @HarshPatel using this i need to setup node but my requirements are limited to JS

Comment: The [official Dropbox API v2 JavaScript SDK](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-js) supports both node and browser JavaScript. There's a thread here about using `filesDownload`: https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/API-support/JS-SDK-filesDownload-How-do-I-get-the-file-content/m-p/238336#M13198

Answer (score 0):

```
   Please check the below answer

   public ActionResult Index()
        {
            SignInToDropBox();
            return View();
        }
        public void SignInToDropBox()
        {
            string[] stringArray = new string[6];
            Program p = new Program();

            p.Main(stringArray);

        }
        class Program
        {
            public void Main(string[] args)
            {
                //var task = Task.Run((Func<Task>)Program.Run);
                //task.Wait();
                var task3 = Task.Run((Func<Task>)Program.Download);
                task3.Wait();
            }

 static async Task Download()
            {

                using (var dbx = new DropboxClient("yHFdFxdeNzAAAAAAAAAAKSONCez08ZrwRJ90Fdf5uvFk-aDkgih661r_KVoUko9Q")) //"Your Access Token
                {
                    string fileName = "D://downloa.pdf";
                   // string file = "ltest.pdf";
                    using (var response = await dbx.Files.DownloadAsync("/Akhil/get.pdf",null))
                    {

                        byte[] toBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(await response.GetContentAsStringAsync());


                        try
                        {
                            using (var fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
                            {
                                fs.Write(toBytes, 0, toBytes.Length);

                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Exception caught in process: {0}", ex);

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: In above code i have used asp.net MVc for developing

Comment: /Akhil/get.pdf is the file you need to download from DropBox and we are writing it to downloa.pdf.

Comment: more reference check:https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/dotnet#tutorial